# Can anyone please help me, Is my letter write?

Tags: editing, academic-writing

My dear XYZ,
I am highly pleased your telephonic invitation that the marriage ceremony of you is going to take place on this (day). Accept my heartiest congratulation on your occasion of enjoyment.
I couldn't certainly attend to your wedding party, as my new job hiring I can't attending to your eve of the marriage ceremony.
Convey my heartfelt congratulation and compliments to you and to all the member of your family. 
with best wishes.

Comment: Proofreading requests are off-topic here, since they're unlikely to ever help anybody else. Closing.

Comment: I see this is the second such question you've asked here. Having a look at our site [tour] might help make it clearer what questions are permitted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you really going to write him a letter after he invited you over phone? Well, not my place to judge.

The writing is just awful. It would be better to write in your native language than in English.

Anyway, have a template:

> Dear {Name},
>
> I received your invitation and am so honored to be included among the
>   people you want to celebrate your nuptials. Unfortunately, I will be
>   unable to attend the wedding due to {reason}.
>
> I'm so sorry to miss your joyful day. I know that your wedding will be
>   perfect and I'm so happy for you. Congratulations, and I wish you all
>   the best!
>
> Sincerely,
>
> {Sender}

{Name} - your friend's name

{Sender} - your name

{reason} - the reason you can't attend (a job opportunity you simply cannot miss)